# Convertion of user-defined object to string by toString not showing correct output

Tags: java, string, tostring, object-to-string

I have created a class `CurrentDate` which shows the system date in a particular format(e.g. 29-JUN-12). The class looks like :

```
package getset;

import java.util.*;
import getset.Getset;
public class CurrentDate{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        String toyear=String.valueOf(year);
        String newyear=toyear.substring(2,4);
        String newmonth=monthvalidation(month);
        System.out.println("Current date : " + day + "-" + (newmonth) + "-" + newyear);
    }

    private static String monthvalidation(int initmonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //int initmonth=i;
        String finalmonth="";
        if(initmonth==1)
        {
            finalmonth="JAN";
        }
        if(initmonth==2)
        {
            finalmonth="FEB";
        }
        if(initmonth==3)
        {
            finalmonth="MAR";
        }
        if(initmonth==4)
        {
            finalmonth="APR";
        }
        if(initmonth==5)
        {
            finalmonth="MAY";
        }
        if(initmonth==6)
        {
            finalmonth="JUN";
        }
        if(initmonth==7)
        {
            finalmonth="JUL";
        }
        if(initmonth==8)
        {
            finalmonth="AUG";
        }
        if(initmonth==9)
        {
            finalmonth="SEP";
        }
        if(initmonth==10)
        {
            finalmonth="OCT";
        }
        if(initmonth==11)
        {
            finalmonth="NOV";
        }
        if(initmonth==12)
        {
            finalmonth="DEC";
        }    
        return finalmonth;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to convert it using `toString()` it does not show what is expected. I tried:

```
CurrentDate date=new CurrentDate();
String sysdate=date.toString();
System.out.println(""+sysdate);
```

It shows something like: `getset.CurrentDate@18a178a` which is not human readable expected format. What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method.

In your `CurrentDate` class, add somethnig like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String toyear=String.valueOf(year);
    String newyear=toyear.substring(2,4);
    String newmonth=monthvalidation(month);
    return day + "-" + newmonth + "-" + newyear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `toString` method in your class . Add a method like a as follows.

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    return day + "-" + newmonth + "-" + newyear;
}
```

Comment: In Eclipse, it is not accepting `day`,`newmonth` or `newyear`.

Comment: Mann..!!!...you should declare those variables as instance variables or   declare them in toString() method

Answer (score 0):

You are not overriding the `Object` implementation of `toString()`
To test your method, you could quickly put the logic in that you have developed into a `public String toString()` method.  then in your `main` method, create a `CurrentDate` and print the `toString`.

Answer (score 0):

I see problem in your code.
First, you are not having fields for which you want `toString()` representation.I think you need to declare fields like:

```
int month;
int year ;
int day;
 @Override
public String toString() {
    return "CurrentDate [month=" + month + ", year=" + year + ", day="
            + day + "]";
}
```

If you are using Eclipse IDE, just generate `toString()` method, that will be a simple solution to your problem. Right now, object `toString()` is invoked for your `toString()`. In fact, as per Josh Bloch,

> every class should override toString() for getting human readable format.

Comment: The variables should be declared within the `CurrentDate` class?

Answer (score 0):

```
CurrentDate date=new CurrentDate();
String sysdate=date.toString();
System.out.println(""+sysdate);

In your above code you are using date object but not assigning  any value , only CurrentDate  class reference. so your are getting 'getset.CurrentDate@18a178a' when use toString() method.

If you want to format date to string you have to use 

public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd-MMM-yy";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
```